# About two sets of the equivalence classes on the same set $A$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

I am reading "Introduction to Algorithms 3rd Edition" by Thomas H. Cormen, Charles E. Leiserson, Ronald L. Rivest and Clifford Stein.

I am reading section 16.4 "Matroids and greedy methods" now.

And the following proposition is used implicitly in a proof of Theorem 16.5 on p.438.
I know this proposition is intuitively obvious.
But I cannot prove it rigorously.
Please tell me a rigorous proof.

Let $A$ be a finite set.

Let $R$ be an equivalence relation on $A$.
Let $\{C_1, \cdots, C_m\}$ be the set of the equivalence classes of the equivalence relation $R$ on $A$.

Let $S$ be an equivalence relation on $A$.
Let $\{D_1, \cdots, D_n\}$ be the set of the equivalence classes of the equivalence relation $S$ on $A$.

Prove the follwoing proposition:

> If $n < m$, then there exist $i \in \{1, \cdots, n\}, j, k \in \{1, \cdots, m\}$ such that $D_i \cap C_j \neq \emptyset$ and $D_i \cap C_k \neq \emptyset$ and $j \neq k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose the statement is false.  Then each $D_i$ intersects at most one $C_j$.  But every element of $D_i$ is an element of $A$ - therefore an element of some $C_k$ - therefore an element of this particular $C_j$.  That is, $D_i$ is a subset of $C_j$.  Thus the union of all $n$ of the $D_i$ is a subset of the union of some $n$ or fewer of the $C_j$; and since $n<m$, this is a proper subset of $A$.  We have shown that $A$ is a proper subset of $A$, and this is a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you very much for your very clear rigorous proof, David.